# KeyInfo not loadable since windows update

Tags: c#, wcf

I am facing the problem, that loading keyinfo data using

```
var encryptedKey = new EncryptedKey();
encryptedkey.LoadXml(rawData);
```

does not work any more. I got a `Mailformed element keyinfo` SecurityException due to the additional `xsi:type` attribute:

```
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="KeyInfoType">
```

Digging into the framework code I found a registry query which can disable strict attribute enforcement.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\Security]
"SignedXmlSkipSignatureAttributeEnforcement"=dword:00000001
```

using this key the keyinfo can be loaded. I did not find any information why this has been changed by the windows update. Are there any ideas how to solve this issue without setting the registry entry? Of course a can remove the attribute by my own, but there must be another solution.